# Help with some book titles

Tags: meaning

重生之妙手医心

> I don't get this because of "妙手医心."  What does it mean?  A wonderful hand and a doctor's heart?

大哥这种生物，少惹为

> What is "少惹为?"

魔天记

> Is it "devil's diary?"

Answer (score 5):

妙手: *magic hands* is a metaphor for skilled person (painter, writer, doctor, etc). There is a phrase '妙手仁心' *magic hands and kind heart* which is used to praise good doctors. '妙手医心' means the same.

少惹为: you're missing a character, it should be 少惹为好 er 少惹为妙, meaning *the less provocation the better*. The whole sentence means *better not provoke the boss*.

魔天记: 魔 generally means *devil*, 天 means *sky or heaven*, 记 means *diary or story*. Without reading the book (suppose it is a book), the exact meaning of 魔天记 isn't clear even in Chinese.

Comment: 魔天记 = story of magic days

Comment: 魔天记 could mean "Tales of Magic Heaven" or even "Tales of Devils' Heaven".

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @NS.X is good enough. But I think you may need a little more background :)
These books are all online-novel, in China it's kind of industry, writers need to type 3000-5000 or more characters per day-so you can imagine the quality...
And their title, sometimes it's just simply add cool characters together(天,地,神,魔,龙,etc) or replace some characters from proverb. They dont have actual meaning in classic Chinese. So if you are trying to translate, better use their concept rather than literally meaning.
Hope this may help.